# What is the result of this function?

Tags: haskell

This is the code I got on my test and I'm wondering what the output would be:

```
funkcija[] _ = 0
funkcija (glava:rep) broj
   | glava > broj = funkcija rep broj
   | glava <= broj = glava + (funkcija rep broj)
funkcija [4,2,1,5,7,6] 2*3
```

Do I compare the head/first number in the array with 6 (2*3) or 2 and then multiply the sum with 3?

Is the correct answer 18 or 9?

Comment: Why don't you just try yourself directly?

Answer (score 2):

Function application takes precedence over operators, so this is interpreted as:

```
(funkcija [4,2,1,5,7,6] 2) * 3
```

Your `funkcija` is in essence a sum that first filters: it only will sum up values that are less than or equal to the second parameter (here `2`), so for `[4,2,1,5,7,6]` this will sum up `2 + 1` which is `3` and then multiply with three to obtain `9`.

The `funkcija` can be replaced with:

```
funkcija :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a -> a
funkcija xs t = sum (filter (<= t) xs)
```

Comment: I just realized I put < instead of > and >= instead of <=, I apologize for that. But it was important for me to find out what takes precedence, so thank you very much. Following that logic and how the code looks now, I'm assuming the answer is 9, right?

Comment: @Mihailo: for `<=` it is indeed `9`.